# Sorting List of List of Long

Tags: java, java-8

Given an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>`, how can we sort the order of elements(lists) in the outer list based on the elements of the inner lists?

### Constraints

1. Only outer list should be sorted.
2. Order of elements in inner list should not be modified.

#### Input:

```
[
    [1],
    [2, 5, 6],
    [6, 5],
    [1, 2],
    [2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3]
]
```

#### Expected output:

```
    [1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2],
    [2, 3],
    [2, 5, 6],
    [6, 5]
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You are downvoted because you don’t have a minimum example of the code you have so far and why it’s not working. Additionally your requirements are unclear. I can think of 3 different ways your second example is sorted from your first. I didn’t down vote you, I’m just explaining the downvotes

Comment: @jlemon, this is not about downvote. Would you like to maintain the order of elements in inner list? or do you want to sort the inner list also?

Comment: @jlemon, i have updated the answer with more details. please check if its useful.

Comment: I downvoted because 1) giving examples is not the same as specifying the logic in dedail. I can figure it out, but it should be written 2) you still didnt show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use element wise comparator

Compare 2 lists by

1. compare in increasing order of index location
2. if any non-zero value is found, return the result
3. else compare the size of the lists
4. sort the lists using this comparator logic

### Use per index comparator chain. Based on WJS's approach

1. Compute the maximum list size across all of the inner lists
2. Create a chain of comparator for every index from 0 to the computed maximum size
3. Use this decorated(chain of responsibility) comparator to sort the lists

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SortNestedList {

    protected List<List<Long>> transform(Long[][] inputArray) {
        return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter outer null lists
            .map(nested -> Arrays.stream(nested)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())) // generate nested list by filtering any null values
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    protected void sortWithElementComparator(List<List<Long>> lists) {
        lists.sort((a, b) -> {
            return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size())) // check till end of minimum sized list
                .map(i -> Long.compare(a.get(i), b.get(i))) // compare elements at same index
                .filter(i -> i != 0) // ignore equal values comparison
                .findFirst() // get first non-zero comparison result (unequal)
                .orElse(Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size())); // if nothing, then compare size
        });

        lists.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    protected void sortWithDecoratedComparator(List<List<Long>> lists) {
        // comparator for an index
        IntFunction<Comparator<List<Long>>> elementAtIndexComparator =
            index -> (a, b) -> index < Math.min(a.size(), b.size()) ?
                Long.compare(a.get(index), b.get(index)) : // compare elements if index is valid for both lists
                Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size()); // compare size if index is invalid for atleast 1 list

        final int maxInnerIndices = lists.stream()
            .mapToInt(List::size)
            .max().orElse(0); // get max inner list size or 0 if empty

        Comparator<List<Long>> listComparator = IntStream.range(0, maxInnerIndices)
            .mapToObj(elementAtIndexComparator) // index comparator for every index
            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing) // kind of chain of responsibility / decorator
            .orElse((a, b) -> 0);

        lists.sort(listComparator);

        lists.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    protected void sort(Long[][] inputArray, int run) {
        System.out.println("Sort input using direct element comparator: " + run);
        sortWithElementComparator(transform(inputArray));
        System.out.println("Sort input using decorated comparator: " + run);
        sortWithDecoratedComparator(transform(inputArray));
    }
}
```

### Test code

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SortNestedList sortNestedList = new SortNestedList();
        int run = 0;

        Long[][] inputArray = new Long[][]{};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{null}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{null}, {1L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{null, {1L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{1L}, {1L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{2L}, {1L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{2L, 1L}, {1L, 3L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{Long.MAX_VALUE, 1L}, {Long.MIN_VALUE, 3L}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);

        inputArray = new Long[][]{{1L}, {2L, 5L, 6L},
            {1L, 2L}, {2L}, {1L, 2L, 3L}, {3L, 2L}, {2L, 3L},
            {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L}, {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L},
            {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L}, {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L},
            {Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE, 1L, 5L, Long.MIN_VALUE + 1, Long.MAX_VALUE - 1},
            {Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE, 1L, 5L, Long.MIN_VALUE + 1, Long.MAX_VALUE - 1},
            {Long.MIN_VALUE}, {Long.MAX_VALUE}};
        sortNestedList.sort(inputArray, ++run);
    }
```

Thanks to Holger and WJS

Comment: @Horse You were correct on my answer.  I believe I fixed it.  Had a constant in there and then had that annoying effective final warning. Thanks!  +1

Comment: @WJS, Thank you. I have added a comment in your answer and have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is proved that question was quite understandable. But someones were not )